# Swift 4 Migration - Inheritance from non-protocol, non class AnyObject

Tags: swift3, swift4

I have my `Swift 3` project that I wanted to convert to `Swift 4`.

When compiling after conversation I get a few errors (all the same) regarding `Inheritance from non-protocol`.

[image]

[image]
This is the class that is triggering the error:

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper


//MARK: - Equatable
func ==(lhs: ProcedureSearchModel, rhs: ProcedureSearchModel) -> Bool {
    return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
}

class ProcedureSearchModel : AnyObject, Mappable, Hashable {

    var procedureUid : String = ""
    var cpt : String = ""
    var description : String = ""

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    //MARK: - Hashable
    var hashValue : Int {
        get {
            return procedureUid.hashValue
        }
    }


    init (procedureUid : String, cpt: String, description : String) {
        self.procedureUid = procedureUid;
        self.cpt = cpt;
        self.description = description
    }

    // Mappable
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        procedureUid    <- map["ProcedureUid"]
        cpt         <- map["CPT"]
        description  <- map["Description"]

    }


}
```

> Any clue on how to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class definition can’t include AnyObject. AnyObject isn’t a class or a Protocol.

You’ll either need to remove AnyObject from your class definition, or replace it with NSObject (if you want it to be an Objective-C compatible class.

```
class ProcedureSearchModel : Mappable, Hashable {

}
```

Or:

```
class ProcedureSearchModel : NSObject, Mappable, Hashable {

}
```